# Php variable scope, top level variables in other included files

Tags: php, constants

I have a 3 php files, lets say `[a,b,c].php`

a.php does

```
$constants=parse_ini_file(ROOT_DIRECTORY."constants.ini", true);
```

b.php uses constants from that file via

```
function func(){
 var_dump($constants["xyz"]["abc"]);
}
```

and c.php includes them both

```
include "a.php";
include "b.php";

func();
```

Now when i visit `/c.php` I expect that it should be able to display the constants, but instead I get `Undefined variable: constants in b.php`

Is this expected to not work? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: FWTW: looks like it should work to me.

Comment: You will have to show `a.php` and `b.php`, and check if variable declaration and access are really in the same scope.

Comment: I tried peppering the files with `var_dump($constants["xyz"]["abc"]);`
And what I am seeing is, it works in `c.php` and top level `b.php` (when included), but not in function level in `b.php` when the function is called.

Comment: php 5.4.6 if it matters

Comment: No, that will not work. PHP doesn't have true global variables; they're all scoped. And `$constants` isn't within your func() implicitly.

Comment: @mario ah.. So top level vars cannot be accessed within functions? odd. Can you post that as an answer with a reference or 2? So here the fix is to pass it in as params? Whats the best way to handle this sort of constants in ini situation?

Comment: @mario thanks for the pointer, I am using `global` to get around this issue